# SQL Server - Running count of distinct customers per quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a rolling customer count by quarter from a table that contains duplicates both across and within quarters. I want to count the first occurrence of a customer only that accumulates over quarters.
The code below gives me the wrong answer - it only counts the distinct customers for each quarter, not cumulatively.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FACT;
CREATE TABLE #FACT("FYQ" VARCHAR(10), "GUN" varchar(5));
INSERT INTO #FACT
    VALUES 
        ('FY2015Q1', 'A'),
        ('FY2015Q1', 'B'),
        ('FY2015Q1', 'B'),
        ('FY2015Q2', 'C'),
        ('FY2015Q2', 'D'),
        ('FY2015Q2', 'E'),
        ('FY2015Q2', 'E'),
        ('FY2015Q2', 'A'),
        ('FY2015Q3', 'F'),
        ('FY2015Q3', 'G'),
        ('FY2015Q3', 'C');

SELECT * FROM #FACT;    

WITH CTE
AS
(SELECT FYQ, COUNT(DISTINCT GUN) AS CNT 
FROM #FACT
GROUP BY FYQ
)
SELECT FYQ,
SUM(CNT) OVER (PARTITION BY FYQ ORDER BY FYQ ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RollingCustCount
FROM CTE;
```

The correct answer will be 2,5,7 for the three quarters in the data.
Thanks!

Comment: What does "the correct answer will be 2,5,7" mean? Q1 contains 2new, Q2 contains 2+3new and Q3 contains 2+3+2new customers?

Comment: Correct - Q1 = A and B - 2 customers. Q2 = A, B, C, D, E - 5 customers. Q3 = A, B, C, D, E, F, G - 7 customers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I:

- **num_cust cte:** - number the occurrences of the customer codes (across all quarters) in order of financial quarter. This means that the A in Q1 gets numbered as 1, the A in Q2 gets numbered as 2.
- **sum_cust cte** - extract only those that are a gun_no of 1 (a newly discoverd customer in that quarter), group and sum them (as a count - could also have used COUNT(*)) giving 2, 3, 2
- **select query**  - establish a rolling summation of the counted new customers, so 2, 2+3, 2+3+2

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FACT;
CREATE TABLE #FACT("FYQ" VARCHAR(10), "GUN" varchar(5));
INSERT INTO #FACT
    VALUES 
        ('FY2015Q1', 'A'),
        ('FY2015Q1', 'B'),
        ('FY2015Q1', 'B'),
        ('FY2015Q2', 'C'),
        ('FY2015Q2', 'D'),
        ('FY2015Q2', 'E'),
        ('FY2015Q2', 'E'),
        ('FY2015Q2', 'A'),
        ('FY2015Q3', 'F'),
        ('FY2015Q3', 'G'),
        ('FY2015Q3', 'C');

SELECT * FROM #FACT;    

WITH num_cust AS (
    SELECT fyq, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY gun ORDER BY fyq, gun) as gun_no
    FROM #fact
),
sum_cust AS (
    SELECT fyq, SUM(gun_no) as sum_gun_no 
    FROM num_cust 
    WHERE gun_no = 1 
    GROUP BY fyq
)

SELECT 
  fyq,
  SUM(sum_gun_no) OVER (ORDER BY fyq ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RollingCustCount
FROM sum_cust
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A simple method uses `apply`:

```
select q.fyq, distinct_gun
from (select distinct fyq from #fact) as q cross apply
     (select count(distinct gun) as distinct_gun
      from #fact f
      where f.fyq <= q.fyq
     ) q;
```

Or, if you count the first appearances, I would do:

```
select fyq, count(*) as starts_this_quarter,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by fyq
from (select f.*,
             row_number() over (partition by gun order by fyq) as seqnum
      from #fact f
     ) f
where seqnum = 1
group by fyq
order by fyq
```